# What is the a4j event sequence?

Tags: javascript, jsf, events, richfaces, ajax4jsf

What is the event sequence of a `a4j:commandLink` or `a4j:commandButton`?

Is it right: `onclick`->`actionListner`->`oncomplete`->`reRender`?

Is `reRender` comes before `oncomplete`?

When `action` happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onclick` JavaScript is called the first when the enduser clicks the generated HTML element. When the JavaScript code does **not** return `false`, then all associated `ActionListener` implementations in the JSF side will be invoked, in the order of their association with the component. If the listeners haven't thrown any exception, then the real `action` will be invoked. When the `action` returns a successful response, then the components specified in `reRender` will be updated in the client side. Finally the `oncomplete` JavaScript will be called.

It's pretty easy to track yourself if you have a debugger in both the client and server side and know how to use it. I strongly recommend Firebug for the client side and Eclipse for the server side. You can of course also always do poor man's debugging using `alert()`s or `System.out.println()`s.