# <a4j:commandButton> in jsp action not working with onclick

Tags: jsp, jsf, richfaces

In jsf, I have a form having   `<a4j:commandButton>` in it.Code for button is :

```
<a4j:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary"   onclick="return validateForm();"  oncomplete="waitModalDivOpen('none');Richfaces.showModalPanel('panel2', {})" action="#{TransactionModel.refundOrCancell}" reRender="panel2,refundMessage" value="Refund/Cancell" />
```

when I use onclick with action in `<a4j:commandButton>` the `action` attribute does not work only `onclick` works.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Does validateForm() return true?

Comment: Is a4j:command wrapped inside h:form tag

Comment: @Makhiel yes it return True.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad yes it is there in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you with your question.

The onclick JavaScript is called first when the user clicks in the generated HTML.
So the action is only called after the onclick.

This is the answered in this question link:

[What is the a4j event sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873017/what-is-the-a4j-event-sequence)